# CloudFormation - Structure of the SAM template is invalid. 'Resources' section is required

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am trying to deploy a lambda using code pipepline and code deploy using sam yml but it fails with following error:

```
FAILED - Transform AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31 failed with: 
Invalid Serverless Application Specification document. 
Number of errors found: 1. Structure of the SAM template is invalid. 
'Resources' section is required
```

The sam.yml is:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: Lambda1
Resources:
callDetails:
Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
Properties:
  Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
  Runtime: python3.6
  CodeUri: .
  Description: 'Lambda Function'
  MemorySize: 128
  Timeout: 30
  Role: 'arn:aws:iam::XXXXXX:role/YYYYYYYYY'
  Environment:
    Variables:
      REGION: ap-southeast-2
```

The buildspec.yml has the following command

```
aws cloudformation package \
  --template-file samTemplate.yaml \
  --s3-bucket XXXX \
  --output-template-file outputSamTemplate.yaml
```

The outputSamTemplate:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Lambda Function
Resources:
 callDetails:
  Properties:
   CodeUri: s3://TTTTTTTTTTTTT/CCCCCCCCC
   Description: callDetails Lambda Function
   Environment:
     Variables:
       REGION: ap-southeast-2
   Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
   MemorySize: 128
   Role: arn:aws:iam::XXXXX:role/validationsLambdas
   Runtime: python3.6
   Timeout: 30
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
 Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
```

Comment: Indentation after the `Resources` line in the sam.yml seems off. is it just a copy-paste mis-alignment while posting here?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had some yml files which had Resource block that were empty, removing those files resolved the issue.